# php str_replace template with placeholders

Tags: php, templates, str-replace

I have one array for data

```
    $data = array(title=>'some title', date=>1350498600, story=>'Some story');
```

I have a template

```
    $template = "#title#, <br>#date(d)#<br> #date(m)#<br>#date(Y)#<br> #story#";
```

All i want is to fit data into template and i know that can be done by str_replace but my problem is the date format. date format is coming from the template not from the data, in data date is stored as php date.
yesterday i tried to ask the same question but i think my question wasn't clear.
Anybody please help me.

Comment: This is going to make your templating engine slow. If I were you I'd have it a simple replacement templating engine.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. What you suggest then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it won't work with str_replace easily so i'm going to use preg_replace

```
$data = array('title'=>'some title', 'date'=>1350498600, 'story'=>'Some story');
$template = "#title#, <br>#date(d)#<br> #date(m)#<br>#date(Y)#<br> #story#"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback('/#(\w+)(?:\\((.*?)\\))?#/', function ($match) use($data) {
    $value = isset($data[$match[1]]) ? $data[$match[1]] : null;
    
    if (!$value) {
        // undefined variable in template throw exception or something ...
    }
    
    if (! empty($match[2]) && $match[1] == "date") {
        $value = date($match[2], $value);
    }
    
    return $value;
}, $template);
```

Instead of using `date(m)` or `date(Y)` you could also do things like  `date(d-m-Y)` using this snippet

This has the disadvantage that you can format only the `date` variable using this mechanism. But with a few tweaks you can extend this functionality.

---

**Note:** If you use a PHP version below 5.3 you can't use closures but you can do the following:

```
function replace_callback_variables($match) {
    global $data; // this is ugly

    // same code as above:

    $value = isset($data[$match[1]]) ? $data[$match[1]] : null;
    
    if (!$value) {
        // undefined variable in template throw exception or something ...
    }
        
    if (! empty($match[2]) && $match[1] == "date") {
        $value = date($match[2], $value);
    }
    return $value;
}

$data = array('title'=>'some title', 'date'=>1350498600, 'story'=>'Some story');
$template = "#title#, <br>#date(d)#<br> #date(m)#<br>#date(Y)#<br> #story#";
// pass the function name as string to preg_replace_callback
$result = preg_replace_callback('/#(\w+)(?:\\((.*?)\\))?#/', 'replace_callback_variables', $template);
```

You can find more information about callbacks in PHP [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: Parse error: parse error in - on line 10 and also let me tell you date format in template is not fixed as i mentioned earlier. it could be just #date(d-m-Y)# instead of #date(d)#,#date(m)#,#date(y)#

Comment: Not yet `if(!isset($data[$match[1]]) {` would not work do something like `$dataMatch = $data[$match[1]];` then `if (! isset($dataMatch)) {`

Comment: @Mogria .. you did not .. but have fixed it

Comment: Thankyou Mogria, it works ! but i have one more thing that i forgot to mention that data array is coming from database and will have more then one array into it i.e.$data = array(
array('title'=>'some title', 'date'=>1350498600, 'story'=>'Some story'),
array('title'=>'some more title', 'date'=>1350498600, 'story'=>'Some new story'),
);

Comment: @alladeen closures (e.g. `function(){ /* ... */}`) where introduced with php 5.3. With php 5.2 or lower you either create a function with a name and pass the function name as string to `preg_replace_callback` or you use the [`create_function()`](http://ch1.php.net/create_function) function

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a templating engine like so:
https://github.com/cybershade/CSCMS/blob/master/core/classes/class.template.php

And then your templates turn out like this:
https://github.com/cybershade/CSCMS/blob/master/themes/cybershade/site_header.tpl
and
https://github.com/cybershade/CSCMS/blob/master/modules/forum/views/viewIndex/default.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Download this file: http://www.imleeds.com/template.class.txt

Rename the extension to .PHP from .TXT

This is something I created years ago, I keep my HTML away from my PHP, always. So see an example below.

```
<?php

include("template.class.php");

//Initialise the template class.
$tmpl = new template;

$name = "Richard";
$person = array("Name" => "Richard", "Domain" => "imleeds.com");

/*
On index.html, you can now use: %var.name|Default if not found% and also, extend further, %var.person.Name|Default%
*/

//Output the HTML.
echo $tmpl->run(file_get_contents("html/index.html"));

?>
```

Comment: I didn't want to overcomplication my answer, but you can also use functions as well, supplying arguments, such as: %function.date|jS F Y%